# Is there a parameter I can use in Java that works with all for-each loops?

Tags: java, iterator, foreach

Suppose I've got a method that accepts an array and processes each element in it using Java's built in [for-each loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), like this:

```
public static void myFun(SomeClass[] arr) {
    for (SomeClass sc : arr) {
        // Stuff is processed here
    }
}
```

This works just fine, but now I want to be able to pass the same method a `List<SomeClass>` instead.  Am I destined to use [Collection.toArray(T [])](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])), or is there a parameter I can use for `myFun()` that accepts any type that can be used in a for-each construct?

To clarify: I want a method signature that will accept any iterable object, be it a primitive array or a Collection.  I can very easily write two methods, with one wrapping the other, but I'm just curious if there's a better way.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no, as arrays do not implement Iterable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest using `Iterable`, `Collection` or `List` as the parameter type.

IMO, collections should be preferred to reference arrays. If you happen to have an array `Arrays.asList` does the conversion nicely. `Arrays.asList` allows gets and sets back through to the array, but obviously not "structural" modifications which would change the array length.

```
myFun(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

You may have to use wildcards in extreme/general cases.

```
public static void myFun(Iterable<? extends SomeClass> somethings) {
    for (SomeClass something : somethings) {
        // something is processed here
    }
}
```

It is noteworthy that `Collections.toArray` and `Arrays.asList` work slightly differently. `asList` keeps the original array to back the collection, so changes to the collection will be reflected in the array. `Collections.toArray` makes a (shallow) copy of the collection data. Making a copy is often what you would want anyway if you are returning an array. Asymmetrically, if you are passing as an argument you generally do not copy (unless storing as a field).

Comment: I agree; for cases like this I use Iterable since it imposes the least burden on implementors. And while it doesn't work with Object[] directly, it's trivial to bridge this with Arrays.asList().

Comment: Yeah. OTOH, the implementation might conceivable want the collection size before iterating, and most code still uses Collection.

Comment: Given that there doesn't seem to be a way to avoid asList() or toArray(), I agree with this logic the most; it makes sense to use Iterable instead of Object[] if I'm expecting input from both.

Comment: (added a paragraph about asList vs toArray)

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Use [`Iterable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). That's what it's for.</strike>

As you said, [`Iterable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) won't handle arrays.

You don't want to use multiple methods wrapping each other. That rules out `Arrays.asList` and `Collection.toArray`.

So the answer to your question is no, there isn't a way. But if you *can* use `Lists`, why would you ever use arrays?

I would still go with `Iterable` here. I like it better than `Collection` because in the past I've had classes that implemented `Iterable` but were not collections; this made it easy for them to lazily retrieve values as needed, and I could use the foreach loop on them.

Comment: If you use Iterable as the parameter, then you get compile errors when you try to pass in primitive arrays.

Comment: Well, I guess this is OO-related. Shouldn't you have to write a wrapper around the arrays?

Answer (score 3):

**you cannot**, java Arrays doesn't implements Iterable:

```
public static int sum(Iterable<Integer> elements) {
    int s = 0;

    for (int i : elements) {
        s += i;
    }

    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    L1: System.out.println(sum(1,2,3));
    L2: System.out.println(sum(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
    L3: System.out.println(sum(new int[] { 1,2,3 }));
}
```

this results in two compile-time errors in (L1 and L3); so you must design your 
method to accept an Iterable (Collections) and/or an Array, at least one method must perform some conversion (to/from array)

**WORKAROUND**:

you may be try with an adapter:

```
public class ArrayIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final T[] array;
    private int i;

    public ArrayIterator(T[] anArray) {
        array = anArray;
        i = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i < array.length;
    }

    public T next() {
        return array[i++];
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

private static int sum(final Integer ... elements) {
    return sum(new Iterable<Integer>() {

        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
            return new ArrayIterator<Integer>(elements);
        }
    });
}
```

you should pay attention only when dealing with primitive arrays; when you use only 
reference object (your case) ArrayIterator + anonymous class are cool

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, there's no single method signature that type-safely accepts both an Iterable and an array. Obviously you could just accept `Object`, but that would be a hack as well.

Long-ish answer: Since the enhanced `for`-loop is effectively defined twice (once for arrays and once for `Iterable`), you'll need to provide two overloaded methods as well:

```
public static void myFun(SomeClass[] array) {
    for (SomeClass sc : array) {
        doTheProcessing(sc);
    }
}

public static void myFun(Iterable<? extends SomeClass> iterable) {
    for (SomeClass sc : iterable) {
        doTheProcessing(sc);
    }
}
```

Although the source of the two methods looks exactly the same, you'll need to define it twice (unless of course you wrap the Array in your own `Iterable` as @dfa outlined).

Comment: "To clarify: I want a method signature that will accept any iterable object, be it a primitive array or a Collection. I can very easily write two methods, with one wrapping the other, but I'm just curious if there's a better way."

Comment: Ok, then I didn't read the question well enough. I hope this one is better.

Comment: Yeah, there's really no other answer. All the "answers" are just workarounds or advice.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little know feature of Java Generics in Java 1.5+ where you can use `<? extends Subtype>` in your method calls and constructors.  You could use `<? extends Object>`, and then anything that deals with those would have access only to methods on Object.  What you might really want is something more like this:

```
List<? extends MyCrustaceans> seaLife = new ArrayList<? extends MyCrustaceans>();
MyShrimp s = new MyShrimp("bubba");
seaLife.add(s);
DoStuff(seaLife);

...

public static void DoStuff(List<? extends MyCrustaceans> seaLife)
{
    for (MyCrustaceans c : seaLife) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

So if you have a base class (like MyCrustaceans), you can use any methods of that base class in DoStuff (or of the Object class, if your parameter is `<? extends Object>`).  There's a similar feature of `<? super MyType>`, where it accepts a parameter that is a supertype of the given type, instead of a subtype.  There's some restrictions on what you can use "extends" and "super" for in this fashion.  Here's a [good place to find more info](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void myFun(Collection<MyClass> collection) {
    for (MyClass mc : collection) {
        // Stuff is processed here
    }
}
```